# Identify this Epiphone les paul model?

Tags: electric-guitar

I need some help to identify my guitar. It is an older Epiphnone les paul model, but I'm not sure what exact model it is. So if anyone knows it, please help me out.

[image: Guitar Hed]
[image: Guitar]
[image: Badge on back of guitar]

Comment: It’s an epiphone les Paul. Are there sub models under that? Anyway you have the serial number, I would go to the epiphone web site and see if they have a serial number lookup tool.

Comment: That's an Epiphone Les Paul Standard Plain-Top, made in November 1995 in the Samick factory in Korea.

Comment: @YourUncleBob that sounds like answer, post it as such and i will upvote.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I assume this question will be closed, because it's not really useful to anyone else. I was just demonstrating that the asker could have Googled the information in a few minutes, like I did. And I don't know much about Gibsons, so I can't turn it into a comprehensive "how to id any Gibson" answer.

Comment: Not a bad question... you got downvoted because you seemingly put no effort into research before posting here... I will +1 you, at least (tomorrow because I already used all my votes today)

Comment: i had one of thoe from same era; cherry tiger stripe. Very fine instrument

Comment: No. Just read the head stock (it's labeled with "model") and look up the serial number if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a serial number, it's quite easy to identify this guitar... With that bit of info, you can simply google "[Insert your guitar maker here] serial number decoder."

I found the below decoder (among other Epiphone decoders) on this [handy Gibson forum](https://forum.gibson.com/topic/139846-epiphone-serial-number-decoding/):

> FYYMMRRRR
>
> ```
> F/FF = factory ID
> Y/YY = year of manufacture
> MM = month of manufacture
> RRRR = ranking number
> ```
>
> Example: 3021234 = Samick Korea / 1993 / February / unit 1234
>
> Example: S3021234 = Samick Korea / 1993 / February / unit 1234
>
> Example: S93021234 = Samick Korea / 1993 / February / unit 1234
>
> Example: SI01021234 = Samick Indonesia / 2001 / February / unit 1234
>
> Example: SI010212345 = Samick Indonesia / 2001 / February / unit 12345
>
> Note: There may be no factory designator for some 1993 and earlier
>   models. A single digit month of manufacture may occur for some 1997
>   and earlier models. The ranking number may consist of any number of
>   digits.

So, as Your Uncle Bob stated in the comments, this is an Epiphone Les Paul made in November by the Samick factory in Korea. **But**, it's the 128th guitar made in either 1985 or 1995... considering the note that "single digit month of manufacture may occur for some 1997 and earlier models," and that the [Samick factory began manufacturing in 1984.](https://samick.fandom.com/wiki/Epiphone)

Comment: 2021. I was trying to identify another one with very similar characteristics. My problem with your conclusions is that standard Epi LP began in 1989 and are all set necks. So, this guitar was built in 1995 and is not a standard.

Comment: You guys only found the year and place it was made. I have been trying to find information about the actual model, and specifications. Those pages don't tell anything about the actual product line, which are the last 4 digits on my guitar

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphone_Les_Paul
 Standard with worn brown on top maybe and possibly maple on the back.